# Redirect to url based on variable using HTACCESS

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, social-networking

I want to make a service that allows users to get a direct link to do an action like follow or subscribe (not telling for obvious reasons).

So using htaccess or php (whatever is better), how can I do the following
example.com/insertusernamehere automatically redirects to somepopularsocialmediasite.com/?follow_user=blahblahblah

It's important to note that the example.com site would be on a different server than somepopularsocialmediasite.com.

Also I would like to have some .html pages including an index.html, about.html, etc etc so I would need a way to exclude certain queries/files from redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you can store the username in a variable somehow, so we could do something like this:

```
$current_url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$username = 'some_username_you_get_somehow';
$url_username = substr(strrchr($current_url, '/'), 1);

if ($url_username == $username)
{
    header("Location: http://somepopularsocialmediasite.com/?follow_user={$username}/");
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response. However, now that I think about it, I would have to use htaccess for what I want to achieve. I want to make it so lets say someone has a socialmedia profile. They can just go to example.com/profilename and it redirects them to socialmediasite.com/?follow_user=profilename

Comment: Sorry, but I can't assist you further as I don't know the .htaccess syntax good enough.

Answer (score 0):

If all the pages that will exist on your server (`index.html`, etc) all have the `.html` extension, you can simply do this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ http://socialsite.com/?follow_user=$1 [R=301, L]
```

Basically, that rule will not match anything that contains an extension, because it's only looking for non-case-sensitive letters and numbers. You can even put hyphens in there if you like.